# Simple android app to print text

Tags: java, android

I recently started watching youtube videos about android development. I watched a few and tried to write my own app. Basically what it does is, the user enters a text in the text field and when the user presses the click button, the entered value is displayed on a text view.

I am very confused as to where I should define variables and how to retrieve values and how to show values on a specific item. I want to know this stuff so I can correctly begin developing android apps. This is the code that I currently have:

```
package com.abihnav.numdisplayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public String YOUR_NUM = "YOUR_NUM";

EditText numEditText;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText numEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numEditText);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

public void printNum(){
    YOUR_NUM = numEditText.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(YOUR_NUM);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Whenever I enter text or a number, the app force closes. HELP?!

Comment: i don't see a button ?

Comment: try this textView.setText(String.valueOf(YOUR_NUM));

Comment: Where is the button ? @Raghunandan `YOUR_NUM` is already a String variable, why do you want to call `String.valueOf()` on it ?.

Comment: You have two variables `numEditText` and `textView` that are duplicated (one local to `onCreate()`, the other global to `MainActivity` (that are never set)). you're going to run into trouble with this!

Comment: @ZouZou i failed to spot that YOUR_NUM is string

Comment: Thank you guys! I cant believe I forgot to instantiate the button and its onClick function. Now this is crystal clear :)

Answer (score 1):

By doing the following:

```
EditText numEditText;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText numEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numEditText);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

You are creating two instances of the same variable. Bad! In order to use these values in other methods you should remove the `EditText` and `TextView` from inside the `onCreate`, like so:

```
EditText numEditText;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   numEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numEditText);
   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

Now you still need to define your Button and its `onClick` method to finish this. Like so:

```
EditText numEditText;
TextView textView;
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   numEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numEditText);
   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
   myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            printNum();
        }
   });

}
```

Also, make sure you have a `<Button>` in your XML file that has the id attribute of `@+id/button_id` for the code to work. (Thanks to ZouZou)

Comment: You should add to create the `button` in the XML file

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I completely forgot to instantiate a button. And its so stupid of me not to add the onClick function. Thank you so much!

Also,where is it better to declare variables? Outside the onCreate function or inside it? I know I declared it twice, but where is the best place to declare variables?

Comment: @AbhinavBhatta I would say all of them out side `onCreate` as I have shown, this allows you to access them (ie, `getText()`) from other methods like you have done with your printNum() method.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for then you may click the tick on the left side to accept it :) however there is no obligation to do so on SO.

Answer (score 1):

like @TronicZomB you could also try this way

```
EditText numEditText;
TextView textView;
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   numEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numEditText);
   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

}
public void printNum(View v)  {
YOUR_NUM = numEditText.getText().toString();
textView.setText(YOUR_NUM);
```

}

and in the XML part

```
<Button
android:id=@id/button_id
android:text="ok"

android:onClick="printNum"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

so by putting that in yer XML directly it'd call the method named printNum and execute it.